# Minimum Gap between visits on a UK 2 year visa

Tags: uk, repeat-visits

Can my parents re-enter UK, before completing 6 months outside UK, using a 2 year visa? They have indian passports

1) My parents got UK visa stamped on 16 nov 2016 and Travelled to UK on 9 dec 2017.

2) Then from UK they fly on 6 Jan 2017 to US and are scheduled to fly back from US to UK on 2 July.

This means although they still have their 2 year visa for UK valid, the time lapse between first and second visit to UK is less than 6 months (actually short by only 4 days).

I want to know if this will be a problem. Can find any such thing on Border agency website

Comment: *Travelled to UK on 9 dec 2017(**6**)*